# Do you know why some C instructions can be completely ignored?

Tags: c, microprocessors

Do you know why some C instructions can be completely ignored? How to avoid this strange behavior?

**Details to replicate the error or to understand where the problem appear**:

When executing this function:

```
static u32 XFpga_GetBitstreamInfo(UINTPTR WrAddr,
                u32 *BitstreamAddress,
                u32 *BitstreamSize) {
    xil_printf("------1----Inside XFpga_GetBitstreamInfo------\r\n");
    u32 Status = XFPGA_SUCCESS;
    u32 PartHeaderOffset;
    u32 BitstreamOffset;

    xil_printf("------2----Before PartHeaderOffset------\r\n");
    PartHeaderOffset = *((UINTPTR *)(WrAddr + PARTATION_HEADER_OFFSET));
    xil_printf("------3----Before BitstreamOffset------\r\n");
    xil_printf("------ART----(WrAddr + PartHeaderOffset + BITSTREAM_PARTATION_OFFSET)=%p------\r\n",(WrAddr + PartHeaderOffset + BITSTREAM_PARTATION_OFFSET));
    xil_printf("------ART----*((UINTPTR *)(WrAddr + PartHeaderOffset + BITSTREAM_PARTATION_OFFSET)) = %u ------\r\n", *((UINTPTR *)(WrAddr + PartHeaderOffset + BITSTREAM_PARTATION_OFFSET)));
    BitstreamOffset = *((UINTPTR *)(WrAddr + PartHeaderOffset + BITSTREAM_PARTATION_OFFSET));
    xil_printf("------4.1----Before *BitstreamAddress------\r\n");
    xil_printf("------4.2----Before *BitstreamAddress------\r\n");
    xil_printf("------4.3----Before *BitstreamAddress------\r\n");
    *BitstreamAddress = (BitstreamOffset * WORD_LEN) + WrAddr;
    xil_printf("------5.1----Before *BitstreamSize------\r\n");
    xil_printf("------5.1----Before *BitstreamSize------\r\n");
    *BitstreamSize = *((UINTPTR *)(WrAddr + PartHeaderOffset)) * WORD_LEN;

    return Status;
}
```

The output is

```
------1----Inside XFpga_GetBitstreamInfo------
------2----Before PartHeaderOffset------
------3----Before BitstreamOffset------
------ART----(WrAddr + PartHeaderOffset + BITSTREAM_PARTATION_OFFSET)=7030001F------
------4.2----Before *BitstreamAddress------
------4.3----Before *BitstreamAddress------
------5.1----Before *BitstreamSize------
------5.1----Before *BitstreamSize------
```

As you can see, all the instructions around the line `*BitstreamAddress = (BitstreamOffset * WORD_LEN) + WrAddr;` are completely ignored (and that's why there are so many "printf" in the code I am proposing in this question: to make clear where the problem is).

**Context:**

- Using zcu102 board developed by Xilinx
- running the compiled code on the PMU processor
- The code I am debugging is part of the XilFPGA library, version 4.0. The source files can be download from [this git repository](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/release-2018.1/lib/sw_services/xilfpga/src/xilfpga_pcap.c).
- I am using Vivado SDK 2018.1 to compile the PMU firmware, and concordantly, the repository 2018.1 for the source code. However, I have tried to use other versions to verify if this strange behavior disappears. The problem is still there.

Any idea on what I can investigate?

Comment: Probably some bad implementation of `xil_printf`... Where is printing to? Serial port?

Comment: Agreed, my first suspicioun would fall on `xil_printf`. Can you verify the behaviour with different debug methods?

Comment: yes, it is! the definition and the implementation of the function `xil_printf` are also part of the Xilinx's libraries BSP.

Comment: @CharonX, I cannot debug in another way now. I am looking for a solution (the situation is complecated: there is a linux kernel running on an quad core ARM A53 and the linux kernel passes some parameters to the PMU -a silicon implementation of a MICROBLAZE in Triple Module R.-). However, xil_prinf is always used in any of the Xilinx's functions: never I found a problem

Comment: Can you disassemble the code though? That way you can see if the function is called 3 times as it ought to be. And if so, the function itself is the culprit.

Comment: This question needs a better title. The content seems good though.

Comment: @Kami Kaze, any title suggestion?

Comment: @Ludin: just found the solution for debugging: https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841724/PMU+Firmware. I would be able to execute the instruction step by step, even the assembler instruction. Going to try

Comment: If something about that pointer write touches am in-memory buffer for print or a hardware device used for print output, that could be causing your missing prints.

Comment: If it is serial output it might use, say, some DMA write to the port without waiting for completion, so the subsequent writes will interrupt is and overwrite. Or it might use a FIFO of limited capacity, where the last writes will overwrite the previous ones. Or similar issues. Just some speculation.

Comment: @Leos313 no not really but I feel that there might be a more descriptive title, that would present the problem better. Especially I think that the "completly ignored" might be wrong, because I think that side effects of the call might happen. Like incrementing a variable in the call as for example `xil_printf("Value = %d",val++);` I think the increment of `val` would happen. If not then it would be really ignored. Other wise there might be just a problem deeper down.

Comment: @LuisColorado, there are details to replicate the error. However, I have "solved" the problem simply using a previous version of the xilfpga firmware (exactly version 2.0 from Vivado 2017.1). Why 2.0? Because It was fully tested by us and works properly after some minor changes (1) to be compatible with the 4.0 version and (2) to perform also a Dynamic and Partial Reconfiguration. It is just a "walk around", not a solution, I know it. I am planning to switch to the new version 4.1 and investigate deep inside what's going on (probably just a matter of wrong flags passed through Linux).

Comment: @Leos313, I'm glad to hear that you solved the problem.. no discussion then!!! everybody's glad :)